# I want to know about nvidia drivers and does they suit me

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 in 64 bit version in a Lenovo laptop. It has the following graphics card:
 Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

I want to know if I can use Nvidia drivers with this graphics card?

Comment: add the complete laptop model number. Also post the result of `lspci |grep -i vga`. generally speaking nvidia drivers are only for nvidia graphics card (which seems you don't have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You appear to have an **Intel** graphics card. Nvidia drivers only apply for Nvidia cards. Intel graphics drivers are supported by the kernel very well, without the need for any additional driver.

Comment: ok.. i understood it . Thnak You.